# Flutter: SVG Image in the background throws an error

Tags: flutter, svg, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have to keep the SVG Image in the background and keep the Text in the top. 
When I'm keeping the SVG Image from the Flutter_SVG Package, I got a error like this.

```
I/flutter (24437): Unsupported operation: Could not resolve image href: Component%206%20-%201-image.png

Picture provider: ExactAssetPicture(name: "assets/images/login_header.svg", bundle: null,
I/flutter (24437):   colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xfff44336)), BlendMode.srcIn))
I/flutter (24437): Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#32e52(), name:
I/flutter (24437):   "assets/images/xxx.svg", colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(MaterialColor(primary value:
I/flutter (24437):   Color(0xfff44336)), BlendMode.srcIn))
```

Comment: ensure your image file name has only small letters and under score.

Comment: @Darish.That is not the issue. The issue is filter effects are not supported in the package yet

Answer (score 1):

`flutter_svg` package that you use does not support `filter effects`.Sadly this is not possible with the current version of the package.This would be possible only.

Anyway one of the hacks (Crappy workaround)

- Converting shadows to bitmap(not correct solution)

Follow the issue on [Github Issues](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/53). Hoping the feature will be available soon as said by the developer of the package

Answer (score 1):

Need to clear the caches from SVG Image. It can be done by SVGCleaner and that's will work in our project.

Answer (score 1):

Download SVG CLEANER ["Download"](https://sourceforge.net/projects/svgcleaner/) and clean the files, then open the .SVG in a text editor and change the following:

and add

That should be enough, I have had this problem several times and only then has it been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by dragging and dropping the svg files to the Figma design tool and then export all of them to get the standard error-free svg files.

Answer (score 0):

Do this `flutter clean && flutter pub get`