# flutter_svg not loading some svg files and throw error

Tags: flutter, svg, svg-filters

I am using the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package(`version` `^1.0.3`). I got svg icons from [fathtericons](https://feathericons.com/) site. But I have erros. I couldn’t find a better solution to this. [filter icon](https://feathericons.com/?query=filter)

Output Error

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
Unable to load asset: assets/icons/task/filter.svg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:72:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AssetBundlePictureProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:546:25)
<asynchronous suspension>

Picture provider: ExactAssetPicture(name: "assets/icons/task/filter.svg", bundle: null, colorFilter:
  null)
Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#75508(), name:
  "assets/icons/task/filter.svg", colorFilter: null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: null, fontSize:
  14.0, xHeight: 7.0))
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

My Code:

```dart
SvgButton(
  svg: 'assets/icons/task/filter.svg',
  onPressed: () {
 },
),
```

```dart
class SvgButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const SvgButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.svg,
    this.width = 24,
    this.height = 24,
    this.color,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String svg;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color? color;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
        svg,
        color: color,
        height: height.w,
        width: width.w,
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
    );
  }
}
```

My `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/
```

My Flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.1.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please try with newer version : ***flutter_svg: ^1.1.0***

Use SVG cleaner or LOAD Assets in pubspec.yaml: see this :

1. [load assets in pubspec.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659809/fluttererror-unable-to-load-asset)
2. [see the answer to the same question download SVG cleaner or upload SVG online and clean it. it works for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336382/13078639)